# UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad in ios

Tags: ios

UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad in ios why it is used ?

in my mac book pro ipad stimulator

```
  BOOL isIPad2 = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad &&
                        [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`  Is used to know what the current device is. From Apple doc

> For universal applications, you can use this property to tailor the
>   behavior of your application for a specific type of device. For
>   example, iPhone and iPad devices have different screen sizes, so you
>   might want to create different views and controls based on the type of
>   the current device.